# Bluetooth mouse lags, then has "delayed playback"

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, lag

My Bluetooth mouse will occasionally freeze for a second, then replay my movements delayed by a second.  This "delayed playback" behavior lasts several seconds, consistently lagging a second behind, before the displayed position suddenly fast-forwards to my current mouse position.

This can happen a couple times a day - the rest of the time the mouse is perfectly responsive.

I haven't noticed any system activity that correlates with the delays (such as heavy I/O).
Also, the mouse has fresh batteries.

I never saw this when using the mouse with the old machine I had - I've only seen it on my new laptop.

How can I go about troubleshooting or preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Event Log for Bluetooth issues. Try to install the same driver version on both machines and see if the issue persists.

Bluetooth uses a wireless technology called FHSS (Frequency hopping spread spectrum), meaning any interference should be intermittent because it has the ability to "hop" frequencies. Bluetooth operates in the 2.4Ghz frequency if I recall correctly, so newer cordless phones and other wireless devices **could** cause intermittent interruption, although very brief.

Answer (score 0):

You can try repositioning your bluetooth receiver. If you need, find an USB extension cord to help reposition the receiver. I would point it straight up if possible. Also would help if you provided model and brand of the mouse. Trying different drivers wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: The Bluetooth receiver is in the laptop, which is 12 inches from my mouse.  The mouse is a Dell DH956.  The drivers I'm using are the standard Windows 7 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

after tried several methods, I found some solution.

1. disable power manager.

[image]

then check every device in device tree, close power save.

[image]

2. disable bluetooth network adapter

[image]

3. add/change register key(remember restart your system)

[image]
[image]

other methods you may need:[Power Management Tab is missing from Device Manager](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/power-management-tab-is-missing-from-device/0a3c563a-5ec7-4809-9609-4bc257444590?auth=1)

If it still doesn't work, try disable bluetooth support service and enable it like this:

[image]

ref:
[蓝牙鼠标时常停住怎么解决？](https://www.zhihu.com/question/282690811/answer/457021129)

[Bluetooth Mouse Lag / Stutter on Lenovo Yoga 7i 14](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Bluetooth-Mouse-Lag-Stutter-on-Lenovo-Yoga-7i-14/m-p/5060439?page=1)